# To check whether the services are disabled

Tags: powershell, service

I have a scenario where I need to check around 100 windows services whether they are disabled or not.

I have the solution of checking the services startup type of "disabled" individually like

```
if(((Get-Service -Name ServiceName).StartType -eq "Disabled")-and((Get-Service -Name ServiceName).Status -eq "Stopped")){
    Write-Output "Service disabled"
 } else {
    Write-Output "Service not disabled"
}
```

Is there any alternative to check services in one go than checking individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$ServicesName='tzautoupdate', 'shpamsvc'
Get-Service -Name $ServicesName | Where Status -eq "Stopped" | %{

"Service {0} is '{1}'" -f $_.Name, $_.StartType

}
```

Comment: Can we get the names of those services which are not disabled?

Answer (score 2):

This simple line work for you

```
Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.StartType -eq "Disabled" -and $_.Status -eq "Stopped" }  | Select -Property "Name"
```

It gives you a list of services which are disabled and stopped.

Comment: the solution specified by you works on single service. How we need to check multple services status and startup type through your solution?

Comment: Gujjar, Can we specify all the services in one line assigned to variable and then pass the variable to check status and startup type?

Comment: sure, you can, like $list = Get-Service -name "*test*"; then $list | ----remaining text---